# How to make a sidebar elements fixed or static when collapsing

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Hi I'm trying to implement a collapsible sidebar but whenever I toggle the collapse button, the elements are moving.

I checked so many questions here on SO but couldn't find a solution.

[JS FIDDLE LIVE DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/gerasg/7wtzo4xL/9/)

I tried deleting all the `padding` in general but that did not work. I'm missing something.

This is the sidebar:

[image]

But when I click the toggle button:

[image]

Some random space is added between the icons and they change the position, how could I keep those icons or elements static/sticky? I don't want them to move.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use this style for sidebar:

```
position: sticky;
top: 0;
align-self: start;
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/huykon225/74923hLd/2/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it is not working, the icons are moving when collapsing the sidebar

Comment: @Cheknov cause your icons have large space so it's problem. Try to remove the spaces

Comment: I tried with the paddings, which spaces should I delete? Could you provide a sample code?

Comment: You can try this https://jsfiddle.net/huykon225/74923hLd/6/

Answer (score 1):

To start, you could try to add this to your css :

```
#sidebar.active .sidebar-header {
  padding-top: 104px;
}
```

This will compensate the size of the picture diseappearing.

Then, I saw that even with the link text hidden, there is still two non breaking space (`&nbsp;`) inside your links. You should remove it and align the text with a `padding-left` instead.

I've saw that you've added `padding: 20px 10px;` for the `#sidebar.active ul li a` but **this will change the padding of your links in the sidenav**, so they won't make the same size anymore. I've removed it.

There will still be a problem : When your sidenav is growing, the text to be displayed won't have the place to expand, so **it will return to the next line**, we don't want that.
To prevent that, you could add a container inside the sidenav, that will **always make the same size**. Or you could try to fix the sizes of your links, so that the text that won't fit won't be displayed, as you choose.

I've edited your [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/polypode/s9hr1kwv/4/).